# Can't apply and display new CSS changes in the browser using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I make changes in my CSS 'Site.css' form (in my Visual Studio's 2012 program), I can see the changes made in the Design View of my Default file, but when I run it in the browser, no new changes are applied.

I tried deleting everything in my CSS file and ran it in the browser, hoping that no CSS would show, but none of the changes were made and it still displayed the default design, despite the CSS being completely wiped clean.

A while ago everything seemed to be working and I was able to make changes. But recently, I can't make any changes when displayed in the browser and it is very frustrating.

I'd like to say again that I can only see the changes in Design View.

Please help.

Comment: You've obviously tried hitting Ctrl F5 in the browser - to force the download of the latest css file?

Comment: @MartinSmellworse Yes. I did it when I deleted all the CSS code and ran it. Still no difference.

Comment: Can you posr your CSS?

Answer (score 1):

The css file is probably in the [browser cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache). Thats probably the reason why styles are applied even when you delete the contents of the file. [Try clearing the cache in chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en)

If clearing the browser cache does not work, go to the [network panel](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#network-panel-overview) in developer tools and check the path of the css file and verify you are editing the same file loaded by the browser.